# WPF Animation execute twice

Tags: wpf

I faced an issue regarding the Animation execute twice, please check the code:

```html
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <ListView x:Name="lstHandled" Grid.Column="0" Visibility="Visible">
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListViewItem>Jimmy</ListViewItem>
            <ListView.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ListView.MouseEnter">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="spAll"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Margin)"
                                From="-100,0,0,0" To="0,0,0,0"
                                AutoReverse="False"
                                Duration="0:0:1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ListView.Triggers>
        </ListView>

        <StackPanel x:Name="spAll" Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Margin="-100,0,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ListView x:Name="Handled">
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <ListView x:Name="UnHandled">
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>World</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
            <StackPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="StackPanel.MouseLeave">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation
                                Storyboard.TargetName="spAll"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(StackPanel.Margin)"
                                From="0,0,0,0" To="-100,0,0,0"
                                AutoReverse="False"
                                Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </StackPanel.Triggers>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

When the mouse leave the "spAll" StackPanel. It fired the Mouse Enter event for the ListView. How to avoid this issue?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both in the same grid column so they overlap and thus the enter/leave events :) Separate them in the UI.